# Jackson Polymorphic Deserialization based on Enum

Tags: java, json, polymorphism, jackson

I'm working with [JacksonPolymorphicDeserialization](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-docs/wiki/JacksonPolymorphicDeserialization), this is my code which deserializes into the proper class based in the 'type' property:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(  
    use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,  
    include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY,  
    property = "type",
    defaultImpl = Event.class, 
    visible = true)  
@JsonSubTypes({        
    @Type(value = SpecialEvent1.class, name = "SPECIAL_EVENT_1"), 
    @Type(value = SpecialEvent2.class, name = "SPECIAL_EVENT_2"), 
    })  
public abstract class AbstractEvent {

    private String type;

    public String getType() {
    return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
    this.type = type;
    }   
}
```

It's working perfectly and my json turns into the expected class according to the 'type' value.

However, I'm considering to move the 'type' property from String to Enum, this is my new code with this change:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(  
    use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,  
    include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY,  
    property = "type",
    defaultImpl = Event.class, 
    visible = true)  
@JsonSubTypes({        
    @Type(value = SpecialEvent1.class, name = "SPECIAL_EVENT_1"), 
    @Type(value = SpecialEvent2.class, name = "SPECIAL_EVENT_2"), 
    })  
public abstract class AbstractEvent {

    private EventType type;

    public EventType getType() {
    return type;
    }

    public void setType(EventType type) {
    this.type = type;
    }   
}
```

and the Enum:

```
public enum EventType {
    SPECIAL_EVENT_1,
    SPECIAL_EVENT_2,
    EVENT;
}
```

The problem is that this second approach is not working... any idea why??? can I use Enum here???

Thanks!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Fixed!

It works with jackson 2.0!!

Comment: Seems if you don't put the  visible to true in this case it wont work....can you confirm?

Comment: I can confirm that `visible` needs to be `true` to work. In my case I also used `include = JsonTypeInfo.As.EXISTING_PROPERTY` to avoid the property appearing twice during serialization.

Comment: Thank you for the visible=true. works perfectly with enums :)

Comment: And what about using the enum value `EventType.SPECIAL_EVENT_1` instead of a String? Is it possible?

Comment: @PhoneixS No, because the name must be a constant.

Answer (score 9):

It worked for me using enum with the following :

```
@JsonTypeInfo(  
    use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,  
    include = JsonTypeInfo.As.EXISTING_PROPERTY,  
    property = "type",
    visible = true
)
```