# Deserializing Polymorphic Types with @JsonUnwrapped using Jackson

Tags: java, jackson, polymorphism, deserialization

**What I Want to Do**

I want to use Jackson to deserialize a polymorphic type, using the standard `@JsonTypeInfo` annotation as follows:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, 
              include = As.EXISTING_PROPERTY, 
              property = "identifier")
@JsonSubTypes({@Type(value = A.class, name = "A"),
               @Type(value = B.class, name = "B")})
abstract Class Base {}

Class A implements Base {
    public String identifier = "A";
}

Class B implements Base {
    public String identifier = "B";
}

Class Decorated {
    public String decoration = "DECORATION";

    @JsonUnwrapped
    public Base base;
}

/* 
    Serialized instance of Decorated WITHOUT @JsonUnwrapped:
    {
        "decoration" : "DECORATION",
        "base" : {
            "identifier" : "A"
        }
    }

    Serialized instance of Decorated WITH @JsonUnwrapped:
    {
        "decoration" : "DECORATION",
        "identifier" : "A"
    }
*/
```

Related post: [Deserialize JSON with Jackson into Polymorphic Types - A Complete Example is giving me a compile error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30362446/deserialize-json-with-jackson-into-polymorphic-types-a-complete-example-is-giv)

This can normally be deserialized by Jackson as follows:

```
public Object deserialize(String body, Class clazz) {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    return objectMapper.readValue(body, clazz);
}
```

(And this would work if the @JsonUnwrapped annotation were removed)

---

**The Problem**

Polymorphic types do not play well with Jackson's `@JsonUnwrapped` annotation, as discussed in this Jira ticket from 2012:

http://markmail.org/message/pogcetxja6goycws#query:+page:1+mid:pogcetxja6goycws+state:results

> Handle polymorphic types with @JsonUnwrapped
>
> Agreed - while fixing things is obviously preferable, improving error messages would be useful if that can't be done.
>
> Unwrapping is one of features where implementations gets complicated enough that any bugs cropping up (on deserialization esp) tend to be antibiotic-resistant...

Hardly encouraging.

Three years later:

http://markmail.org/message/cyeyc2ousjp72lh3

> Handle polymorphic types with @JsonUnwrapped
>
> Resolution: Won't Fix

Damn.

So, is there any way to coax Jackson into giving me this behaviour without modifying `deserialize()` or removing the `@JsonUnwrapped` annotation?

Comment: Have you managed to solve this or to find a workaround?

Comment: I haven't, no. You can always implement a custom serializer that delegates serialization of Base back to Jackson after writing the 'decoration' field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My `SinglePolyUnwrappedDeserializer` from [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/Anton3/348e639b6d46c3598f3311b9feca8578) can handle a single polymorphic `@JsonUnwrapped` property. It's in Kotlin, but can easily be ported to Java if needed. Example:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(
    use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,
    include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY,
    property = "type"
)
@JsonSubTypes(
    JsonSubTypes.Type(value = A::class, name = "a"),
    JsonSubTypes.Type(value = B::class, name = "b")
)
abstract class Base

data class A(val x: Int) : Base()

data class B(val y: Boolean) : Base()

@JsonDeserialize(using = SinglePolyUnwrappedDeserializer::class)
data class C(val a: String, @JsonUnwrapped val b: Base)
```

AFAIK, all combinations of other annotations are supported. The only limitation is that there is exactly one `@JsonUnwrapped` property.

If you also need a generic serializer for polymorphic `@JsonUnwrapped`, you can write it yourself very easily without any reflection or introspection: just merge the `ObjectNode` of the inner object onto the `ObjectNode` of the containing object.

Comment: Can you elaborate on serialization? A JsonSerializer has a JsonGenerator, so it's not clear how you serialize the inner object to an ObjectNode?

Comment: @TomQuarendon `(gen.codec as ObjectMapper).valueToTree<ObjectNode>(inner)` (Sorry for not answering for months, lol. At the time I thought it's obvious enough, and I only needed the deserializer)