# Jackson polymorphic Json Deserialization in java

Tags: java, json, jackson, polymorphism, deserialization

My Json can be:

```
{                                     
    "bird": "Owl",
    "Animal": {
        "type": "Dog",
        "breed": "mutt"
    }
}
```

Or

```
{
    "bird": "Owl",
    "Animal": {
        "type": "Cat",
        "color": "white"
    }
}
```

Class for Json,

```
Class ABC {

     public String bird;

     Animal animal;

}


@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY,property = "type")
@JsonSubTypes({
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value=Dog.class,name="dog"),
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value=Cat.class,name="cat") }
)

Class Animal {

    public String type;

}

Class Dog extends Animal {

   public String breed;

}

Class Cat extends Animal {

   public String color;

}
```

when i read json,

```
ObjectMapper solver = new ObjectMapper();

Objectabc = solver.readValue(new File(filename), ABC.class);
```

I am able to access `bird`,but

`Objectabc.animal.type` prints `null`.

Please tell me how can i access `type` and `breed` or `color`.

Comment: This is because you don't deserialize the property `type` as you use it to instantiate the right `Animal` subclass. So instead try to print: `Objectabc.animal.getClass().getName()`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30362446/deserialize-json-with-jackson-into-polymorphic-types-a-complete-example-is-giv