# Deserialize jackson with abstract Type

Tags: java, json, jackson, abstract-type

I'm a beginner in java so i'm not really sure if the title is right but i've been trying to unmarshal a json string of which i won't know the type in advance.

```
  public interface Dummy<T>  {
      T unmarShall(String item);
  }

  abstract class  DummyAbstract implements Dummy<T> {

      protected T unmarShall(String item){
          ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

          try {
              T objectx = mapper.readValue(item, T);
              return objectx;
          }
      }

      }


  }
```

As this method is expecting a Class as the second parameter

```
              T objectx = mapper.readValue(item, T);
              return objectx;
```

I've been reading about how to do this but can't really find a proper way to do this.

I would only call this method from an subclass like :

```
   public class DummyImpl extends DummyAbstract<MyClass>{
   }
```

I've been doing it with the class hardcoded into the implementation for now but that not DRY at all..

could that be done ?

Comment: You've probably already found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30362446/deserialize-json-with-jackson-into-polymorphic-types-a-complete-example-is-giv

Comment: Any solution to this?