# Passing of list of type Baseclass between Webservices involving generics and conversion of polymorphic types

Tags: spring, generics, jackson, resttemplate

I have two REST services using Spring Boot running on two different servers. I am using REST Template for this communication.

There are some models that are shared by these two services. All these models are of type 'IDataToTransferred' .

'IDataToTransferred' is a marker Interface implemented by various Model Beans.

I need to write a common logic for passing a list of these models between these REST services.

Hence I wrote a logic which uses parameters 
    `List<? extends IDataToTransferred>` from Sender service to Receiver Service.

**Update: With Some Code**

*IDataToTransferred.java* is a marker Interface

*DataToBeSent.java*

```
DataToBeSent Implements IDataToTransferred{
   //Simple Pojo
}
```

*SenderService.java*

```
sendData(List<? extends IDataToTransferred> uploadDataObjectList){
//Some Code with REST Template
//restTemplate.postForEntity
}
```

*IDataToTransferred* Interface is shared between communicating webservices.

*DataToBeReceived.java*

```
DataToBeReceived Implements IDataToTransferred{
//Simple Pojo
}
```

*ReceiverService.java*

```
receiveData(List<? extends IDataToTransferred> uploadDataObjectList){
//Some Code to convert uploadDataObjectList to  DataToBeReceived
}
```

Note In REST service I was always getting 415 error. Unsupported Media type. when I use the same `List<? extends IDataToTransferred>` on Receiver.

When I changed this to `List<? super IDataToTransferred>` on Receiver side, now it works, I am guessing because of Producer extends Consumer super rules.

But the problem is that now I can't typecast to the IDataToTransferred type on Receiver Side. Inside the list I am getting all linkedHashmap, the json got converted to linked HashMap between these services.

How can I get DataToBeReceived class object in ReceiverService?

For simplicity sake I have removed Controllers. Assume that they have the same signature as the services.

Comment: Which answer do you expect? You have not posted a line of code. There are no magic which can solve problems from some unclear explanations.

Comment: Sure. I will post the code. Though I got a solution using @JsonSubTypes

Answer (score 0):

If I had known better terms to search, I would have found answer before Posting. But alas.

In any case I found the answer in stackoverflow page [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30362446/deserialize-json-with-jackson-into-polymorphic-types-a-complete-example-is-giv/30386694#30386694) together with a [this](http://programmerbruce.blogspot.in/2011/05/deserialize-json-with-jackson-into.html) blog ofcourse.

The examples are with abstract classes. I have used with interfaces.

As mentioned in the link. I Introduced below annotation in the marker interface *IDataToTransferred*:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(
    use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,
    include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY,
    property = "type")
@JsonSubTypes({
@Type(value = DataToBeSent.class, name = "datatransfer")})
```

The property *type* is introduced in the bean *DataToBeSent* as a property. This type param is used as information for conversion into implementing type from interface type. One can use a different variable than one named "*type*". In JsonSubTypes annotation , we mention the classes that are implementing this interface.

```
DataToBeSent Implements IDataToTransferred{
 //Simple Pojo
 // Some Properties with getter and setter
  String type = "datatransfer";
//with getter and setter
}
```

The same exercise needs to be implemented on the Receiver Side also. Hence, we will have annotation as below:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(
    use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,
    include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY,
    property = "type")
@JsonSubTypes({
@Type(value = DataToBeReceived.class, name = "datatransfer")})
```

Here, we have DataToBeReceived class as implementing the *IDataToTransferred* interface. Ofcourse you need to add type as property to *DataToBeReceived*  class also as below:

```
DataToBeReceived Implements IDataToTransferred{
 //Simple Pojo
 // Some Properties with getter and setter
  String type = "datatransfer";
//with getter and setter
}
```

Hope this helps.