# Converting json to java where a field is of interface Type

Tags: java, gson

I have a JSON like

```
{
   "age" : "35",
   "otherdetails":{
   "address" : "xyx",
    "pincode" : "978897"
    }
}
```

I have a base class to covert JSON TO JAVA

```
 class Base
 {
     int age;
     OtherDetails otherdetails;
 }
```

also i have an interface for otherdetails and a class implementing the interface

```
interface OtherDetails
class AddressDetails extends OtherDetails
{
   String address;
   String pincode;
}
```

How can i use gson or jackson to convert the json so that it picksup AddressDetails class when converting thee otherdetails attribute?

Comment: Do you have any code to show us what you have tried to do?

Comment: So what happens here? is values are null or is it gives you an exception ?

Comment: Asking for 'which library' is off-topic here.

Comment: i@Vimukthi_R I was getting blank values when i tried to access the fields address

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find the answer in [Deserialize JSON with Jackson into Polymorphic Types - A Complete Example is giving me a compile error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30362446/deserialize-json-with-jackson-into-polymorphic-types-a-complete-example-is-giv)

I tried similar kind of thing and it worked

Comment: The solution was to add a new attribute in my json like classname in which i populate the correct classname eg AdressDetail. Then at the interface level i had to add annotation with the classname attribute