# Inheritance deserialisation with jackson in java

Tags: java, jackson, jackson-databind

I have 3 child classes named CreditAccount, Savings Account & ChequingAccount that extends one superclass named Account.

I am trying to save all the users with their respective account details in a HashMap as follows:

```
public HashMap<Long, HashMap<String, Account>> userAndHisAccountsObject;
```

where the HashMap has UserID as key and a HashMap object as its value that contains AccountType as Key and respective account details its value.
I am successfully able to serialize this object but when I try to deserialize it, it throws `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidTypeIdException`

can I get any solution to my issue?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-docs/wiki/JacksonPolymorphicDeserialization

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer has indeed been provided in the comments by @hollpolloi with the link: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-docs/wiki/JacksonPolymorphicDeserialization

When you are using inheritence and Jackson you need a way to tell jackson how to differentiate different JSON from each other, and how to decide which object-type (class) each one is. **The problem is that Jackson can get confused with similar JSON payloads when there is no attribute that tells jackson what class should be used**.

Another good reference q/a is : [Deserialize JSON with Jackson into Polymorphic Types - A Complete Example is giving me a compile error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30362446/deserialize-json-with-jackson-into-polymorphic-types-a-complete-example-is-giv)

A very simple solution is to annotate your classes with something like the following:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "@class")
public abstract class Animal {
   ...
}
```

See also:

- https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/misc/jackson/jackson-json-type-info-annotation.html

Comment: Thanks @menelaos-bakopoulos & @ hollpolloi for your answer. It worked.