# Problem with Deserialization of Generic Classes

Tags: java, spring, generics, jackson, polymorphism

I came across a problem with `Generics` and `Jackson` recently and ended up with not using it.
I have an interface `MonetaryType`:

```
public interface MonetaryType implements Serializable {}
```

which is implemented by multiple `enum`s like:

```
public enum IncomeType implements MonetaryType {
    FULL_TIME_SALARY,
    PART_TIME_SALARY,
    CHILD_BENEFIT
}

public enum ExpenseType implements MonetaryType {
    HEAT,
    CONDO_FEES,
    ELECTRICITY
}
```

I created a Generic Class:

```
public MonetaryValidation<T extends MonetaryType> {
    
   private T monetaryType;
   private boolean isPassed;
   private String message;

   // Getters and Setters

}
```

This object is not deserialized by Jackson library. Meaning that if any Spring REST endpoints are called while the payload contains `MonetaryValidation` object, it throws below exception:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot construct instance of
> `**.enumeration.MonetaryType` (no Creators, like default construct,
> exist): abstract types either need to be mapped to concrete types,
> have custom deserializer, or contain additional type information

I do not want to solve the issue with [Jackson polymorphic deserialization approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30362446/deserialize-json-with-jackson-into-polymorphic-types-a-complete-example-is-giv) since it requires the client to pass an extra flag specifying the concrete implementation of the interface or abstract class, as far as I understood.

Unfortunately I ended up creating multiple sub classes of non-generic `MonetaryValidation` (one subclass per each `MonetaryType` subclass), which I know it is not a decent solution.

It is much appreciated if you could help me out to understand where the problem is and whether there is an approach to use `@JsonSubTypes` while passing an extra field is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

There is an idea, try accept *monetaryType* as the *String* type parameter, and you can custom converter in the *Generic* class for handling the *generic* type field, such as:

```
        public void setMonetaryType(String monetaryType) {
            Optional<IncomeType> incomeType = Arrays.stream(IncomeType.values()).filter(i -> i.name().equals(monetaryType)).findFirst();

            incomeType.ifPresent(i -> {
                this.monetaryType = (T)i;
            });

            Optional<ExpenseType> expenseType = Arrays.stream(ExpenseType.values()).filter(i -> i.name().equals(monetaryType)).findFirst();

            expenseType.ifPresent(i -> {
                this.monetaryType = (T)i;
            });
        }
```

I think this is a simply way to achieve other than using `JsonSubTypes` or custom Converters,  since it's really a *generic* parameter.

Comment: Thanks for your response, This could be an expensive approach since per each Rest call it iterates over N loops and instantiates N Optional objects, where N is the number of MonetaryType sub-classes.
However, it is a clean approach, it encapsulates all the dirty work in one setter method.

Comment: @AliK.Nouri but I think you can define an abstract class to encapsulates the common converter if it's possible.

Comment: Yes but that needs to change monetaryType type to String. I'm trying to find a way not to do that.