# Validate different POST requests, one endpoint

Tags: java, validation, spring-restcontroller

Two types of POST requests are sent to the "/numbers" endpoint:

```
{
    "type": "A",
    "numberOne": 1
}
```

and

```
{
    "type": "B",
    "numberOne": 1,
    "numberTwo": 2
}
```

How to validate for type A that numberOne is not null and for type B that numberOne and numberTwo are not null? I was able to find explanations of how to achieve this with two different endpoints and validation groups, but not how to achieve this with one endpoint.

```
@RestController
public class NumbersController {

    @PostMapping("/numbers")
    public Numbers addNumbers(@Valid @RequestBody Numbers numbers) {
        // Create data. 
        return numbers;
    }
}
```

```
@Data
public class Numbers {
    private String type;
    @NotNull
    private Integer numberOne;
    @NotNull
    private Integer numberTwo;
}
```

Comment: You need a polymoprhic JSON deserializer. If you're using Jackson (you seem to, the default JSON deserializer for a Spring MVC application), then https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30362446/deserialize-json-with-jackson-into-polymorphic-types-a-complete-example-is-giv can help you. Also make sure you have `ObjectMapper` properly configured. Note that using polymorphic objects can be very hard to maintain in the future, so you can consider using distinct endpoints unless it's a real "no-no".