# How to determine subclass for deserialization based on a nested type property?

Tags: java, jackson, polymorphism

I have an interface `Node` and three classes that implement it: `Root, Junction` and `Leaf`. I wish to deserialize a list of Nodes from a JSON string. Each node in the JSON string looks something like this:

```
{  
parameters: {  
    type:<node_type>,  
    some_more_properties  
    },
childNodes:{some_more_nodes}  
}
```

How can I determine subtypes of `Node` according to the type inside of `parameters`. Which classes should I extend, how should I extend them and how to add them to the ObjectMapper/Annotation?

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Deserialize JSON with Jackson into Polymorphic Types - A Complete Example is giving me a compile error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30362446/deserialize-json-with-jackson-into-polymorphic-types-a-complete-example-is-giv)

Comment: It doesn't, the provided example is the vanilla case of polymorphic deserialization. My case is more complex because I need to determine the correct subclass according to a nested property.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to achieve this by using custom deserializer:

```
public class CMNodeCustomDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<CMNode> {

private final Map<String, Class<? extends CMNode>> registry = Map.of("ROOT", CMRootNode.class,
                                                               "JUNCTION", CMJunctionNode.class,
                                                               "LEAF", CMLeafNode.class);

public CMNodeCustomDeserializer() {
    super(CMNode.class);
}

@Override
public CMNode deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext deserializationContext) throws IOException {
    ObjectMapper mapper = (ObjectMapper) jsonParser.getCodec();
    JsonNode root = mapper.readTree(jsonParser);
    String type = root.get("parameters").get("type").asText();
    return mapper.treeToValue(root, registry.get(type));
}
```

}