# ClassCastException when I use a list of objects in a POST API in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, jackson

I want to create a simple REST API for a POST request in a Spring Boot project. For this POST request, I need to use this payload:

```
[
{
 "name": "John",
 "user_name": "johnny",
 "email": "johny@gmail.com",
 "phone": "0000",
 "id": "435445",
 "tag": "zxcvb"
},
{
 "name": "John",
 "user_name": "johnny",
 "email": "johny@gmail.com",
 "phone": "0000",
 "business": "abcd",
 "data": "qwert"
}
]
```

I can't change this payload model, there is a list with 2 objects and the 2 objects have 4 common fields and different fields.

And I implemented the `RestController`:

```java
@RestController
@Slf4j
public class DataController {
    @PostMapping("/data")
    DataResponse createData(@RequestBody List<CompleteRequest> completeRequests) {
        log.info("completeRequests = {}", completeRequests);
        DataResponse response = new DataResponse();
        response.setName(completeRequests.get(0).getName());
        response.setUserName(completeRequests.get(0).getUserName());
        response.setEmail(completeRequests.get(0).getEmail());
        response.setPhone(completeRequests.get(0).getPhone());
        response.setId(((TagRequest) completeRequests.get(0)).getId());
        response.setTag(((TagRequest) completeRequests.get(0)).getTag());
        response.setBusiness(((DataRequest) completeRequests.get(1)).getBusiness());
        response.setData(((DataRequest) completeRequests.get(1)).getData());
        return response;
    }
}
```

For the request body, I'm using a superclass and 2 subclasses because there are 4 common fields in the 2 objects of the list. So my payload should be a list of 2 different objects. Is that a good approach or should I do something else? Or how can I do a list that stores 2 different objects?

```java
@Getter
@AllArgsConstructor
public class CompleteRequest {
    @JsonProperty("name")
    private String name = null;

    @JsonProperty("user_name")
    private String userName = null;

    @JsonProperty("email")
    private String email = null;

    @JsonProperty("phone")
    private String phone = null;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "CompleteRequest{" +
                "name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", user_name='" + userName + '\'' +
                ", email='" + email + '\'' +
                ", phone='" + phone + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}


@Getter
public class TagRequest extends CompleteRequest {
    @JsonProperty("id")
    private String id = null;

    @JsonProperty("tag")
    private String tag = null;

    @Builder
    public TagRequest(String name, String userName, String email, String phone, String id, String tag) {
        super(name, userName, email, phone);
        this.id = id;
        this.tag = tag;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "TagRequest{" +
                "id='" + id + '\'' +
                ", tag='" + tag + '\'' +
                '}' + super.toString();
    }
}


@Getter
public class DataRequest extends CompleteRequest {
    @JsonProperty("business")
    private String business = null;

    @JsonProperty("data")
    private String data = null;

    @Builder
    public DataRequest(String name, String userName, String email, String phone, String business, String data) {
        super(name, userName, email, phone);
        this.business = business;
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "DataRequest{" +
                "business='" + business + '\'' +
                ", data='" + data + '\'' +
                '}' + super.toString();
    }
}
```

And response class:

```java
@Getter
@Setter
public class DataResponse {
    @JsonProperty("name")
    private String name = null;

    @JsonProperty("user_name")
    private String userName = null;

    @JsonProperty("email")
    private String email = null;

    @JsonProperty("phone")
    private String phone = null;

    @JsonProperty("id")
    private String id = null;

    @JsonProperty("tag")
    private String tag = null;

    @JsonProperty("business")
    private String business = null;

    @JsonProperty("data")
    private String data = null;
}
```

But when I try to make a POST request I get 500:

```
2023-11-07 20:56:52.139  INFO 14288 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] com.dgs.restserver.api.DataController    : completeRequests = [CompleteRequest{name='John', user_name='johnny', email='johny@g
mail.com', phone='0000'}, CompleteRequest{name='John', user_name='johnny', email='johny@gmail.com', phone='0000'}]
2023-11-07 20:56:52.157 ERROR 14288 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exc
eption [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: class com.dgs.restserver.pojo.CompleteRequest cannot be cast to class com.dgs.restserver.pojo.TagRe
quest (com.dgs.restserver.pojo.CompleteRequest and com.dgs.restserver.pojo.TagRequest are in unnamed module of loader java.net.URLClassLoader @5ad6cc21)] with root cause

java.lang.ClassCastException: class com.dgs.restserver.pojo.CompleteRequest cannot be cast to class com.dgs.restserver.pojo.TagRequest (com.dgs.restserver.pojo.CompleteRequest and com.
dgs.restserver.pojo.TagRequest are in unnamed module of loader java.net.URLClassLoader @5ad6cc21)
        at com.dgs.restserver.api.DataController.createData(DataController.java:25) ~[classes/:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:189) ~[spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) ~[spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar
:5.1.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.4.RELEASE.j
ar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:800) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.
1.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]        
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1038) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:908) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:92) ~[spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) ~[spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:834) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1417) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When polymorphic classes are used in a REST API, Jackson can't determine which type of `CompleteRequest` subclasses should be instantiated for each list element.

In your particular case, the list elements are instantiated as  `CompleteRequest` objects, thus ignoring unused fields. Consequently, those objects cannot be cast to child classes, so the `ClassCastException` is thrown.

One simple way to handle this is to define a type hint, as follows:

```java
@Getter
@AllArgsConstructor
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, property = "type")
@JsonSubTypes({
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value=DataRequest.class, name = "DataRequest"),
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value=TagRequest.class, name = "TagRequest")
})
@NoArgsConstructor
public class CompleteRequest {...}
```

The `type` property should be added to the request body, which would Jackson use to determine which subclass to instantiate.

```
[
    {
        "type": "TagRequest",
        "name": "John",
        "user_name": "johnny",
        "email": "johny@gmail.com",
        "phone": "0000",
        "id": "435445",
        "tag": "zxcvb"
    },
    {
        "type": "DataRequest",
        "name": "John",
        "user_name": "johnny",
        "email": "johny@gmail.com",
        "phone": "0000",
        "business": "abcd",
        "data": "qwert"
    }
]
```

To make it work add a default constructor to the subclasses by marking them with `@NoArgsConstructor`.

---

If you have no way to change the incoming payload or must not do so, the `DEDUCTION` type for the `@JsonTypeInfo` annotation, introduced in the `2.12` version of Jackson, can be used. But, as Xobotun mentioned in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65685243/10231374):

> I'd still recommend to use `use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME`, as the new way [may throw an exception](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/blob/fc56ab2e07980b9e2a4316272b99fef57f2a64bb/src/main/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/jsontype/impl/AsDeductionTypeDeserializer.java#L84) in complex cases when it has no way to determine which subtype to use.

Since this case is pretty simple you don't have to worry.

```java
@Getter
@AllArgsConstructor
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.DEDUCTION)
@JsonSubTypes({
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value=DataRequest.class),
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value=TagRequest.class)
})
@NoArgsConstructor
public class CompleteRequest {...}
```

For reference: [Applying polymorphism to a REST API using Spring Boot](https://totheroot.io/article/applying-polymorphism-to-a-rest-api-using-spring-boot)

Answer (score 0):

If you use 'CompleteRequest' as the request body, you will lose all data that is unknown to the 'CompleteRequest' class. Consequently, your JSONs will be serialized to the 'CompleteRequest' object in the request, which doesn't contain any fields other than the four defined ones. See:
[image]

So, you need to specify a request object that contains all the fields you can send in JSONs, such as:

```
@Getter
@AllArgsConstructor
public class CompleteRequest {
    @JsonProperty("name")
    private String name = null;

    @JsonProperty("user_name")
    private String userName = null;

    @JsonProperty("email")
    private String email = null;

    @JsonProperty("phone")
    private String phone = null;

    @JsonProperty("id")
    private String id = null;

    @JsonProperty("tag")
    private String tag = null;

    @JsonProperty("business")
    private String business = null;

    @JsonProperty("data")
    private String data = null;
```

When you receive a request, you can obtain the required fields (regarding class naming, your 'CompleteRequest' is more like a 'PartialRequest.').

In this case, the 'DataController' will look like this:

```
@RestController
@Slf4j
public class DataController {
    @PostMapping("/data")
    DataResponse createData(@RequestBody List<CompleteRequest> completeRequests) {
        log.info("completeRequests = {}", completeRequests);
        DataResponse response = new DataResponse();
        response.setName(completeRequests.get(0).getName());
        response.setUserName(completeRequests.get(0).getUserName());
        response.setEmail(completeRequests.get(0).getEmail());
        response.setPhone(completeRequests.get(0).getPhone());
//        response.setId(((TagRequest) completeRequests.get(0)).getId());
//        response.setTag(((TagRequest) completeRequests.get(0)).getTag());
//        response.setBusiness(((DataRequest) completeRequests.get(1)).getBusiness());
//        response.setData(((DataRequest) completeRequests.get(1)).getData());
        response.setId(completeRequests.get(0).getId());
        response.setTag(completeRequests.get(0).getTag());
        response.setBusiness(completeRequests.get(1).getBusiness());
        response.setData(completeRequests.get(1).getData());
        return response;
    }
}
```

Also, process null values in the request (i.e., don't set null values). Another way is to just use a `List<Object>` in the request. It will be cast to a LinkedHashMap, and you can process it as a map. Alternatively, use a `List<Map<String, String>>` as the request:

```
@PostMapping("/data")
    DataResponse createData(@RequestBody List<Map<String, String>> completeRequests) {
        log.info("completeRequests = {}", completeRequests);
        DataResponse response = new DataResponse();
        response.setName(completeRequests.get(0).get("name"));
        response.setUserName(completeRequests.get(0).get("user_name"));
        response.setEmail(completeRequests.get(0).get("email"));
        response.setPhone(completeRequests.get(0).get("phone"));
        response.setId(completeRequests.get(0).get("id"));
        response.setTag(completeRequests.get(0).get("tag"));
        response.setBusiness(completeRequests.get(1).get("business"));
        response.setData(completeRequests.get(1).get("data"));
        return response;
    }
```