MobX in Flutter/Dart: How to design a "polymorphic" reactive model?
how to design a "polymorphic" model? I have Meta with 2 children, FooMeta and BarMeta. I tried doing this:
meta.dart:
part 'meta.g.dart';

class Meta extends _Meta with _$Meta {
  Meta({
    required super.key,
    super.label,
  });
}

abstract class _Meta with Store {
  String key;

  @observable
  String? label;

  _Meta({
    required this.key,
    this.label,
  });
}

foo_meta.dart:
part 'foo_meta.g.dart';

class FooMeta extends _FooMeta with _$FooMeta {
  FooMeta({
    required super.key,
    super.label,
    super.value,
  });
}

abstract class _FooMeta extends Meta {
  @observable
  String? value;

  _FooMeta({
    required super.key,
    super.label,
    this.value,
  });
}

But foo_meta.g.dart is never generated.
My goal is to create a hierarchy of Meta that maps to polymorphic JSON. E.g.
{"key": "Foo", "value": "Some string"} mapped to FooMeta while {"key": "Bar", "value": {"rich": "data"}} mapped to BarMeta}. In Java world, this is how you'd do it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30386694
